# How to Ping from a Cisco IP Phone 7945G?

Tags: cisco, cisco-7900-ip-phones

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to ping from a Cisco IP Phone? Specifically a 7945G running SCCP45.9-4-2SR1-1S  ? I have successfully gained SSH access to the CLI of the phone, however I don't see a ping command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Cisco's documentation, they recommend you place a workstation in the same VLAN as the phone and use that for ping, etc.

"Determine if you can ping the Cisco CallManager server from a device on the same subnet as the nonfunctional phone. If you can ping the server, you have a minimum level of IP connectivity between the two devices. This allows you to see all the packets that the phone sends and receives during the boot and registration process."

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/voice-unified-communications/unified-ip-phone-7900-series/5710-phone-reg.html